# wrong (same) django template returned for every url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

For any url I type into the browser, the same template is returned. The template in question is ***index.html***.

If I send a request **172.0.0.1:8000/login** or **172.0.0.1:8000/sign-up**, I will get the same html. Even if I try something like **172.0.0.1:8000/sadsajdpojsapfpojpa** the same template will be rendered.

So if anyone has an idea what the problem is, please help!

This is my urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from adventureApp import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^sign-up/$', views.signup),
        url(r'^sign-up-2/$', views.signup2),
        url(r'^sign-up-3/$', views.signup3),
        url(r'^$', views.home),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^login/$', views.login),
    ]
```

This is my views.py file:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")


def login(request):
    return render(request, "login.html")


def signup(request):
    return render(request, "sign-up.html")


def signup2(request):
    return render(request, "sign-up-2.html")


def signup3(request):
    return render(request, "sign-up-3.html")
```

And of course, I have all of these templates (html files) in the templates directory.

Comment: Can you update with your question with project url ?

Comment: what about `TEMPLATES` setting in your settings.py?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the regex on your urls.py, you're forcing all the urls to end with a trailing slash

change them to:

```
url(r'^sign-up/?$', views.signup),
```

hope this helps